# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_arguement'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that has the user select a starting location from a list of vectors, select a destination from that same list using `vec.push_back()` to use the same list minus 1 number. The code should then take the latitude and longitude from those locations and get the distance and flight time between them.

Entering the numbers works fine, but after I enter them the terminal states:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod
bash: line 12: 19106 Aborte
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<tgmath.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define JET_SPEED 518 //Closest to middle between min and max
#define RADIUS 3958.8 //Radius of Earth doesn't change

double haversine(double lat1,double long1,double lat2,double long2)
{
    double d = sqrt(pow(sin((lat2-lat1)/2),2)+(cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*(pow(sin((long2-long1)/2),2))));
    //Per the final simplified equation
    return 2*RADIUS*asin(d);
}
double getFlightTime(double lat1,double lat2,double long1,double long2)
{
    double d = haversine(lat1,long1,lat2,long2); 
    return (double)d/JET_SPEED;
}
int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back("Miami Beach, FL, USA 27.793449       -80.139198");
    vec.push_back("Fargo, ND, USA       46.877186       -96.789803");
    vec.push_back("Idaho city, ID, USA  43.828850       -115.837860");
    vec.push_back("Zion, IL, USA        42.450806       -87.845978");
    vec.push_back("Cairo, IL, USA   37.007828   -89.184265");
    vec.push_back("Lewes, DE, USA   38.781082   -75.157150");
    vec.push_back("Danville, IL, USA    40.144653   -87.634216");
    vec.push_back("Toccoa, GA, USA  34.578903   -83.331581");
    vec.push_back("Venice, FL, USA  27.109644   -82.448792");
    vec.push_back("Torrington, CT, USA  41.806595   -73.130592");
    cout<<"Select departure location from the following options" << endl;
    int num=1;
    int inputInteger=1;
    for(auto tp:vec)
    {
        cout<<num<<". "<<tp<<endl;num+=1;
    }
    cin>>inputInteger;
    
    string dep = vec[inputInteger-1];
    vec.erase(vec.begin()+inputInteger-1);

    cout<<"Select destination location from the following options" <<endl;
    num=1;
    for(auto tp:vec)
    {
        cout<<num<<". "<<tp<<endl;num+=1;
    } 
    cin>>inputInteger;

    string ar = vec[inputInteger-1];

    stringstream tkn(dep);

    string temp;
    num=0;
    double lat1,long1,long2,lat2;
    vector<string> tp1,tp2;
    while(getline(tkn,temp,' '))
    {
        tp1.push_back(temp);
    }
    lat1 = stod(tp1[tp1.size()-2]);
    long1 = stod(tp1[tp1.size()-1]);
    stringstream tkn2(ar);
    num=0;
    while(getline(tkn2,temp,' '))
    {
        tp2.push_back(temp);
    }
    lat2 = stod(tp2[tp2.size()-2]);
    long2 = stod(tp2[tp2.size()-1]);
    cout<<"\nThe haversine distance is : "<<haversine(lat1,long1,lat2,long2)<<"\n";
    cout<<"\nTime take to reach the destination : "<<getFlightTime(lat1,long1,lat2,long2)<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the code to see with what you call `stod`?

Answer (score 1):

From [`std::stod()`'s documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/),

> If no conversion could be performed, an `invalid_argument` exception is thrown.

This means that the argument you're passing to the call to `std::stod()` is not valid for the conversion to happen, and thus it throws an `invalid_argument` exception, which you are not catching.

To **solve** this, make sure the argument to `std::stod()` is valid, or catch the exception.